# alignment using StyledDocument in drag and drop java

Tags: java, swing, drag, jtextpane

I tired from search the solution for this: i want to align text pane from left to right however but drag and drop java this is last code i written :

```
  ` StyledDocument doc = txtio.getStyledDocument();
    Style style = txtio.addStyle("right",null);
    StyleConstants . setAlignment (style, StyleConstants .ALIGN_RIGHT);

try {

    doc.insertString(0,txtio.getSelectedText(), style);

    }
    catch (BadLocationException ex) { 
    Logger . getLogger ( mswordframe.class.getName() ).log(Level.SEVERE,null, ex);
    }

    txtio.setStyledDocument(doc);`

 txtio : is the name of text pane;
```

it doesn't work ,
Sorry i am weak in english

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JTextPane supports `character` and `paragraph` attributes. Character attributes are for pieces of text and paragraph attributes are for a whole line of text.

Alignment of text is a paragraph attribute because you can't have part of the text center aligned and part right aligned for the same line of text.

Try the following:

```
SimpleAttributeSet green = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setForeground(green, Color.GREEN);

SimpleAttributeSet right = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setAlignment(right, StyleConstants.ALIGN_RIGHT);

try
{
    doc.insertString(0, txtio.getSelectedText(), green);
    doc.setParagraphAttributes(0, 1, right, false);
}
catch(Exception e) {}
```